# How to do Database Change Management System in Snowflake from BitBucket? DDL Versioning for DEV/QA/UAT/PROD Environments in Snowflake from BitBucket?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi Everyone,
I have a current Requirement with DDL Versioning/Database Change Management System from BitBucket to Snowflake Cloud. Is there any kind of documentation to achieve this Task.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve question quality

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange for database change management.  It covers the instructions specific to Snowflake, then you'll need to separately setup the BitBucket pipeline (e.g. https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/python-with-bitbucket-pipelines/)